# Remove-AzureKeyVaultKey : Key not found.. Powershell, resource manager

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-cmdlet, azure-keyvault

Trying to remove a key from our Key Vault, using Powershell. But I get the error message "Remove-AzureKeyVaultKey : Key not found".

I'm able to get-AzureRmKeyVaultKeys, but there is no cmdlet for removing key in RM.

When browsing MSDN there is a page for Remove-AzureRmKeyVaultKey, but in the details they're writing Remove-AzureKeyVaultKey.

Comment: did you try to remove the key in pipe? `get-AzureRMKeyValutKey -VaultName 'YourKey' | Remove-AzureKeyVaultKey` or maybe with `get-AzureRMKeyValutKey | where { #Filter# } | Remove-AzureKeyVaultKey `

Comment: The cmdlet is the non-RM version "Remove-AzureKeyVaultKey".  Do you have permission to remove the key?